# get node value from string xml

Tags: c#, xmldocument

I have this string XML

```
string innerXml = @"<detail><WCFFaultExcepcion xmlns=""http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CIEL.DigiturnoMega.Entidades"" xmlns:i=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""><ErrorId>b7e9d385-9118-4297-baca-db9ab00f3856</ErrorId><Message>Índice fuera de los límites de la matriz.</Message></WCFFaultExcepcion></detail>";
```

This is the stringXML

```
<detail>
    <WCFFaultExcepcion xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CIEL.DigiturnoMega.Entidades" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <ErrorId>b7e9d385-9118-4297-baca-db9ab00f3856</ErrorId>
        <Message>Índice fuera de los límites de la matriz.</Message>
    </WCFFaultExcepcion>
</detail>
```

What I want is to get the value of the detail Tag, I’m trying with this example but all return null o cero count, could you help me?

```
 private static void Example()
        {
            string innerXml = @"<detail><WCFFaultExcepcion xmlns=""http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CIEL.DigiturnoMega.Entidades"" xmlns:i=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance""><ErrorId>b7e9d385-9118-4297-baca-db9ab00f3856</ErrorId><Message>Índice fuera de los límites de la matriz.</Message></WCFFaultExcepcion></detail>";

            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(innerXml);

            XmlNode node = (XmlNode)doc.DocumentElement;
            XmlNode optionalNode = node.SelectSingleNode("/detail/WCFFaultExcepcion");
            XmlNode optionalNode1 = node.SelectSingleNode("detail/WCFFaultExcepcion");
            XmlNode optionalNode2 = node.SelectSingleNode("/detail/WCFFaultExcepcion/ErrorId");
            XmlNode optionalNode3 = node.SelectSingleNode("detail/WCFFaultExcepcion/ErrorId");
            XmlElement optional = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"/detail/WCFFaultExcepcion/ErrorId") as XmlElement;
            XmlElement optiona2 = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"detail/WCFFaultExcepcion/ErrorId") as XmlElement;
            XmlNode xNode = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("ErrorId")[0];
            XmlNodeList xnList = doc.SelectNodes("/detail/WCFFaultExcepcion");
            XmlNodeList xnList1 = doc.SelectNodes("detail/WCFFaultExcepcion");
            XmlNodeList xnList2 = doc.SelectNodes("/detail/WCFFaultExcepcion/ErrorId");
            XmlNodeList xnList3 = doc.SelectNodes("detail/WCFFaultExcepcion/ErrorId");
        }
```

Comment: I dont understand what you really want in the end. Can you give us an example... what do you mean with `What I want is to get the value of the detail Tag`. Are you expecting a node? A nodelist? a string? an array of strings? and what should be in them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this might be the solution for you:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(innerXml);
XmlNodeList errorIdTags = doc.GetElementsByTagName("ErrorId");
if(errorIdTags.Count == 0)
{
    // The tag could not be fond
}
else
{
    // The tag could be found!
    string errorId = errorIdTags[0].InnerText;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Swen that how it´s done, but as I know that in all cases I’m getting the ErrorId Tag I decide to use this code:
'XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(innerXml);

string errorIdTags = doc.GetElementsByTagName("ErrorId")[0].InnerText;'

Comment: I would still recommend that you check if the tag exists, try to cover as much errors as possible.

Comment: Doesn't `ErrorIdTags.Count <= 1` give `true` when `ErrorIdTags.Count == 1` and there is `ErrorIdTags[0]`. It should be `ErrorIdTags.Count <1`!

Answer (score 1):

Try using Linq to Xml (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) - the code will be really elegant.

Answer (score 0):

The first try `XmlNode node = (XmlNode)doc.DocumentElement;` should work and should contain children. Try `XmlNode firstChildNode = node.FirstChild;` ... this will get you the first child, and won't be empty/null.

But when using xpath, you will get into problems because of the defined namespace. You will have to create a new namespace in doc, and assign **`http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CIEL.DigiturnoMega.Entidades`** a shorthand (eg.  **`sh`** ) ... then later in your xpath you can like go `doc.SelectSingleNode(@"/detail/sh:WCFFaultExcepcion/sh:ErrorId")`